# Calculating number of tile sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, combinations, fibonacci-numbers

My daughter (aged 12) came to me with the problem below. I was able to help her to some extent but I could not see an age-appropriate solution. That is, I could imagine solutions involving factorials / combinations or writing a computer program. However she is in Year 7 at school and I could not see how to solve it with that level of knowledge. We settled on a brute-force solution but did not complete it as it would take too long. So can anyone solve this with a simple, logical algorithm using knowledge / techniques that a student just starting high school would be familiar with?

Say you have a set of black (B) and white (W) tiles - identical apart from colour. You arrange the tiles in various sequences, eg. B, BW, WWBW, etc. A sequence is considered to be significant if all of its sub-sequences of white tiles are even in length. Thus the following are significant: WW, BBB, WWWWBB; while the following are not: W, BWWW, BWWBBBW. Note: a sequence of length zero would appear to be deemed even.

There were a few simple questions we could solve, eg. how many significant sequences of length 1, 2, 3 and 4 are there. Enumerate them.

But the question that stumped us was: how many significant sequences of length 20 are there. We could not extrapolate easily from the earlier questions.

PS: I wasn't sure what tags to use. Please update as you see fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of significant sequences of length $n$. If you count carefully, you’ll find that $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, $a_3=3$, $a_4=5$, $a_5=8$, and $a_6=13$. You (or she) might recognize these as the [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number), and even if you don’t, you might notice that each is the sum of the previous two. If you extrapolate on this basis, you can guess (after a bit of arithmetic) that $a_{20}=10946$.

Of course you might wonder whether the extrapolation is legitimate. To see that it is, suppose that $\sigma$ is a significant sequence of length $n$, where $n\ge 3$. If $\sigma$ ends in B, the first $n-1$ letters of $\sigma$ are a significant sequence of length $n-1$. Conversely, if you start with any significant sequence of length $n-1$, adding a B to the end gives you a significant sequence of length $n$. Thus, there are $a_{n-1}$ significant sequences of length $n$ that end in B.

If, on the other hand, $\sigma$ ends in W, then it must actually end in WW, and the first $n-2$ letters of $\sigma$ must be a significant sequence of length $n-2$. Conversely, if you start with a significant sequence of length $n-2$ and add WW to the end, you get a significant sequence of length $n$. Thus, there are $a_{n-2}$ significant sequences of length $n$ that end in W.

Putting the two together, we see that $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$.

Comment: Nice answer. Fibonacci and induction is something the student has a handle on. I'll run it by her.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to answer this than mine, but I'l post mine anyways.

Group the white tiles into pairs of 2 - this is done as we only want even sequences of the white tiles. Now, for arranging 20 tiles, we have the following ways to chose the tiles:

- 0 white tiles and 20 black tiles
- 1 pair of white tiles and 18 black tiles
- 2 pair of white tiles and 16 black tiles
  ........ so on until:
- 10 pair of white tiles and 0 black tiles

Consider the first case, when there are no white tiles. There's only one possible combination. In the second case, where there's 1 pair of white tiles, we have 19 possible combinations. When we have 2 pairs of white tiles, we have 153 possible combinations... and so on.

Adding all of them will give us our answer.

**EDIT:**

If we have $x$ items, out of which $m$ are of one kind and $n$ are of another kind, then the total number of ways to arrange them is: $$\frac{x!}{m!n!}$$
In our case, we have two types of objects, pairs of white tiles (which are considered as 1 object) and black tiles.

So, in the third case (two pairs of white tiles), we have a total of 18 objects - 16 black tiles and 2 pairs of white tiles. So, the total way or arranging them is: $$\frac{18!}{16!2!}$$

Comment: That's sort of what we were trying, but how do you get the number of combinations in the non-trivial cases. For example, the "2 pairs of white tiles" (allowing for adjacency and so on) noting the restrictions on math knowledge.

Comment: Give me a sec. I'll edit.

Comment: There, that should help. This is a slightly lengthy method, but it's the only thing that came to mind. I'm surprised that this is a question being asked to a 12 year old......

Comment: Me too! It is the advanced / extension stream, but I don't think they've done factorials (and combinations) yet. I could solve it that way, but not another way.

Comment: BTW, do you have a typo in your answer? 18!/16!2! is 153 not 113?

Comment: @dave I don't think it's possible to solve this question simply by observation. And I do believe that any answer would have to use the concept of factorial. And a typo, I doubt. A calculation error, quite possible. Calculations aren't my forte. Please accept if question is solved.